# Mockito and JUnit : Which is the best to use Runner or TestRule?

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I'm writing some tests with JUnit and Mockito.

I've noticed that Mockito provides a [JUnit Runner](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html) and a [JUnit TestRule](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/junit/MockitoRule.html)

Which are the pros and cons of each solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a rule provides more flexibility than a runner. There can be only one runner, whereas you can have multiple rules in one test class.

Since Mockitos runner and rule apparently do the same I don't see a reason to use the runner here.

For the sake of completeness, I'd like to mention that there is no need to use Mockito's rules (or runners) unless you want to use mock annotations or `validateMockitoUsage()`.

For consistency I usually create all mocks with `mock()` as quite often tests have mocked fields as well as mocked local variables.